# Как сверстать круговую диаграмму с фоновым изображением?

Tags: html, css, svg

**Внимание! Это дубль вопроса с тостера! Автор не я**, просто вопрос показался интересным:

Добрый день. Возникла необходимость сверстать круговую диаграмму с фоновым изображением, что бы можно было редактировать процент заполнения. Пытался сделать с помощью SVG, но скудные знания в этой области не позволили это реализовать. Причем нужно решение без использования jQuery библиотек, можно на ванильном JS, либо с использованием VUE.

**UPD:** Полупрозрачная подложка под диаграммой просто отдельное изображение, которого потенциально может и не быть. Интересует только создание диаграммы.

**UPD 2:** Я в курсе что нарушил Правила сообщества, не предоставив хоть попыток решения, но я считаю, здесь вопрос не кода, а подхода к решению данного вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Alexandr_TT призываю тебя!))

Comment: картинку дизайнер рисовал?

Comment: это не 75% если что :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ картинка взята с вопроса на Тостере, и, думаю, да, рисовал диз)) Обычно им пофиг на такое, главное нарисовать

Comment: @DaemonHK там же дали ответ уже ..продублировать ? https://toster.ru/q/657070

Comment: @MaximLensky если это единственное адекватное решение, то можно и продублировать, думаю, а то людей, имеющих аккаунты и там и здесь, мало))

Comment: @DaemonHK мне в западло воровать чужие ответы ... хочешь ответь сам - я плюсану ..

Comment: @MaximLensky ок)) Вечером дома попробую сделать без SVG, наткнулся на статью одну, если не получится, продублирую ответ с пометкой.

Comment: @DaemonHK лучше на canvas - вот это я хотел бы увидеть

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На картинку наложена маска из серого круга и белого сектора.

Для того чтобы нарисовать сектор нужно посчитать вторую точку дуги по формуле.

```js
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

  // процент заполнения
  let percent = Math.min(99.99, Math.max(0, (e.y-20)/(innerHeight-40)*100));
  
  // радиус сектора
  let r = 120;
  
  // угол второй точки сектора
  let angle = percent/50*Math.PI - Math.PI/2;
  
  // признак большой дуги
  let largeArc = percent > 50 ? 1 : 0;
  
  // аргументы команды ARC 
  let arc = [r, r, 0, largeArc, 1, Math.cos(angle)*r, Math.sin(angle)*r];

  // устанавливаем сектору
  path.setAttribute('d', `M0,${-r}A${arc}L0,0z`);
  
  text.innerHTML = percent.toFixed() + "%";
  
});
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
<svg viewbox="-150 -150 300 300" style="height:100vh" id=svg>
<defs>
  <mask id=mask>
    <circle r=100 fill=gray></circle>
    <path id=path fill=white></path>
  </mask>
</defs>
<text id=text text-anchor=middle font-size=28px font-family=arial y=-122></text>
<image mask="url(#mask)" width=300 height=300 x=-150 y=-150 
       xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/63/300/300"></image>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: салам ...нижнюю часть вообще не видно ..

Comment: и так тоже но уже треть не видно

Comment: @MaximLensky понятно, ff клал на 100vh, сейчас подпилю

Comment: как ты догадался что я с ff ?

Comment: @MaximLensky я его открыл и посмотрел

Answer (score 3):

По просьбам трудящихся добавляю вариант с канвой, тут уже почти ничего считать не надо, т.к. на входе у команды рисующей дугу уже углы.

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let image = new Image();
image.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/63/300/300";
image.onload = e => draw(ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat'));
addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

function draw(e){
  let percent = Math.min(99.99, Math.max(0, (e.y||0-20)/(innerHeight-40)*100));
  let angle = percent/50*Math.PI - Math.PI/2;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  arc(0.5, 100, 0, Math.PI*2);
  arc(1.0, 120, -Math.PI/2, angle);
}

function arc(alpha, radius, startAngle, endAngle){
  ctx.globalAlpha = alpha
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2,radius,startAngle,endAngle);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=300 height=300/>
```

Comment: Интерактивность на мышке доставляет))

Comment: @DaemonHK без нее не интересно, можно было от слайдера, но я решил так, по вертикали

Comment: спасибо за канву ..